# React-Simple-Map not scaling / Map is very small

Tags: reactjs, react-simple-maps

I am attempting to create an interactive map of my home country using `react-simple-maps`, I am facing an issue where the map I am rendering in is extremely small, I have tried using `height/width` and scale but I cannot seem to get the map to render larger than `scale(8)`.

Minimum useable code recreation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/zoom-controls-forked-g47m1?file=/src/MapChart.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your code, you can check solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zoom-controls-forked-519vp?file=/src/MapChart.js).
The problem vas that `scale` property in your JSON map data was too small.
If you want to make your map even more bigger change `scale` prop in `ComposableMap`.

Comment: I was thinking that might have been the issue but this is the first time playing with GeoJson so i was unsure. It looks a little squished on the X axis but that is perfect, i'll tinker to get the X axis fixed. Legend

Comment: May i ask how you figured out what scale to add to the json? thanks

Comment: Of course, I found an JSON map data example on google for some other country (Vietnam I think) and I took scaling property from there and putted it in JSON data for your country and it was working fine.